# JS Censoring algorithm

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, string

In javascript i have an array with words i would like to censor after putting some text in textarea, and when the word in it matches one in array, it is being replaced with "****". The problem is: for example the banned word is "word1", and when i trigger the event with clicking on "censor" button, the textarea.value, which is (for example) "word1!" is being replaced on "*****", but i want it to be "*****!".

There are no loops, cause i just tried to apply the algorithm for single banned word. Couldn't even do that. The 'start' variable is for further searching of other banned words within the textarea.value. Everything should be done with basic string/array methods, without using Regular Expressions.

```js
let getId = x => document.getElementById(x);
let banned = ['word1','word2','word3'];
let start = 0;

getId('censor').addEventListener('click', function(){
let stars = '';
for(let i=0;i < banned[0].length; i++) {
    stars+= '*';
}
let str = getId('text').value;
str = str.split(' ');
let found = str.indexOf(banned[0],start);
str.splice(found,1, stars);
str = str.join(' ');
getId('text').value = str;
})
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <form action="">
        <input type="text" id="banInput">
        <input type="button" value="Add word" id="add">
    </form>
    <textarea name="" id="text"></textarea>
    <input type="button" value="censor" id="censor">
</div>
```

Comment: You could use [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to replace the exact word that was found with the stars and that would keep the rest of the word intact.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to use a regular expression to filter each word against a list of censored words.

Below i do this inside of a [String.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) statement to simplify the process.

```js
//Censor function
var censored = [];
function censor(input) {
    return input.replace(/\w+/igm, function (word) {
        if (censored.some(function (cWord) { return cWord.toLowerCase() === word.toLowerCase(); })) {
            return word.replace(/./igm, '*');
        }
        return word;
    });
}
// HTML NODES
var inputField = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("textarea"));
var outputField = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("textarea"));
outputField.readOnly = true;
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
var listInput = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("input"));
listInput.title = listInput.placeholder = "insert censored words, seperate by \" \"";
listInput.value = '';
//Update functions
function updateOutput() {
    outputField.value = censor(inputField.value);
}
function updateCensorList() {
    censored = listInput.value.split(" ");
    if (censored == null) {
        censored = [''];
    }
    else {
        censored = censored.map(function (a) { return a.trim(); });
    }
    updateOutput();
}
//Bind events
listInput.addEventListener("change", updateCensorList);
listInput.addEventListener("keyup", updateCensorList);
inputField.addEventListener("change", updateOutput);
inputField.addEventListener("keyup", updateOutput);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let getId = x => document.getElementById(x);
let banned = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3'];

getId('add').addEventListener('click', function() {
  banned.push(getId('banInput').value)
  getId('banInput').value = ''
  console.log(banned)
})

getId('censor').addEventListener('click', function() {

  let str = getId('text').value;
  let arr = str.split(/\b/) // array of words
  let censored = arr.map(word => banned.includes(word) ? //if word is in banned
    '*'.repeat(word.length) // replace with *
    :
    word) // leave as is

  getId('text').value = censored.join(''); // back to string
})
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form action="">
    <input type="text" id="banInput">
    <input type="button" value="Add word" id="add">
  </form>
  <textarea name="" id="text"></textarea>
  <input type="button" value="censor" id="censor">
</div>
```