# need help finishing a word cencor in discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

So I have to make a code which censors a word.

The censored word is as***** so,

```
let censor = "#####";
client.on('message', message => {
    let edit = message.content.replace(/asshole/gi, censor);
    message.delete();
    message.channel.send(`${message.author.username}: ${edit}`);
}
```

Currently this is how it works:

> Input:   i am a asshole
>
> Output:  (user) = i am a #####**

I want to make the bot send the `output[(user) = i am a #####]` only when the censored word is in the message. Currently it works on every message.

How can I fix this?

Comment: This probably is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53393292/js-censoring-algorithm

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Don't do the delete + send if there were no changes:

```
client.on("message", (message) => {
  let edit = message.content.replace(/asshole/gi, censor);
  if(edit === message.content) return;  // <- Added.
  message.delete();
  message.channel.send(`${message.author.username}: ${edit}`);
});
```

Comment: You've got a good point, but as this answer doesn't solve the OP's question it should've been posted as a comment.

Comment: @Jakye I'm not quite following. It completely solves OP's question. "I want to make the bot send the output only when the censored word is in the message." If the censored message is the same as the original, the bad word wasn't in the original.

Comment: Oh, you're right. I misread the question. My bad. I'm sorry.